# Export Crashlytics Crashes Report Log

Tags: curl, http-post, crashlytics

I need to export the Crashlytics Crashes Report Log into some external file system. Using their hooks will not work as those are only for new reports whereas I need to export the full open issues. I have found this library: https://github.com/MattNewberry/crashstats but it seems that Crashlytics are blocking it from working.

Looking at the chrome debugger, I am trying to replicate the call to their API using curl so I can later code it in Java/ Ruby:

> $ curl --data "email=user@example.com&password=pass" --referer
>   "https://w ww.crashlytics.com/login" --header
>   "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, * /*; q=0.01" --header
>   "X-CSRF-Token:E5puPaolZYUNJ2IbUX2u9S+W0iqU/6/9KDr4ivcmOq0= " --header
>   "X-CRASHLYTICS-DEVELOPER-TOKEN:0bb5ea45eb53fa71fa5758290be5a7d5bb867
>   e77" --header "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest"
>   https://www.crashlytics.com/api /v2/session

ButI keep getting the following response:

> {"message":"Request not valid"}

Comment: Not having any joy with this either - did you get any further?

Comment: Unfortunately not. They responded a couple of weeks later to ask some question and then nothing back. I have a feeling they like to keep the data in THEIR silo. So if you have a choice, go for another solution.