# Get Crashlytics reports on JSON reports

Tags: elasticsearch, crashlytics

Is there any way get like ( API ?) to get Crashlytics reports as Json data so that i can push it into Elastic search ?

I tried on

http://github.com/MattNewberry/crashstats

But it does not seems to be working for me.

[Export Crashlytics Crashes Report Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613130/export-crashlytics-crashes-report-log)

Any solution ( Preferably in Java or Python ) will be great help